# A misinterpretation of the reversed() function?

Tags: python

I am fairly new when it comes to python; however, I've read some books and I'm currently studying EVERY built-in function , method and module. I have come across the function: reversed().I know the argument 'seq' deals with an iteration AND the iter() object has to support the **reversed**() method. To me, logically, this would work:

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
it=iter(x)
reversed('it')
"""returns the statement "<reversed object at 0x02738730>" """
it.__next__()
1
```

excuse me if this question appears stupid, assuming I misinterpreted the reversed() function.

**My Question**: How exactly does this function behave with iter objects?

Comment: Actually your trying to reverse the string `it` not the iter object `it`

Comment: I was trying to reverse the x[], now that ive read all your answers ive found out that to reverse the list id need to do: it=reversed(x) then following that it.__next__() and my list would iterate reversed. I suppose that's the entire point of the reversed function, to create a reverse iteration. I appreciate all the answers they all helped, primarily @BrenBarn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few problems.  First of all, you reversed the string `'it'`, not your iterator object.  If you want to reverse the object `it`, you need to do `reversed(it)`.

However, that still won't work because `reverse` doesn't work on generalized iterators.  As you note, the object to be reversed has to provide a `__reversed__` method --- which iterators in general do not --- or be a sequence.  (So to answer your question of "How exactly does this function behave with iter objects?", the answer is "It doesn't work on iterables in general; they have to be "special" iterables that know how to reverse themselves.)

You also need to use your result.  `reversed` doesn't reverse the iterator in-place (which wouldn't even be possible); it returns a *new* iterator that goes in reverse.  So, assuming `it` as an object that could be reversed, you'd need to do `rev = reversed(it)` and then iterate over `rev` to see the reversed items.

Answer (score 1):

The reversed() function returns an iterator over the reversed list. It does not reverse the list itself. 
In addition, you're calling the function on the string 'it' and not the iterator you call it, but I'm sure you'd sort that out presently.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x=[1,2,3,4]
>>> it=iter(x)
>>> ti=reversed('it')
>>> print ti.next()
t
>>> ti=reversed(x)
>>> print ti.next()
4
>>> print ti.next()
3
>>> print ti.next()
2
>>> print ti.next()
1
>>> print it.next()
1
>>> print it.next()
2
>>> ti=reversed(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument to reversed() must be a sequence
```

So `reversed` returns returns an iterator object that takes a **sequence** as a parameter and iterates from the end rather than the start.  So reverse will not work with an iterator as a parameter in your example `'it'` is a string with will work but not as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like this, though maybe my crystal ball is foggy today:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

x = [1,2,3,4]
x.reverse()
#it = iter(x)
#reversed('it')
for element in x:
    print(element)
```

We're reversing in place, and then iterating using a for loop.

Comment: my intent was fully understanding the function, I was trying to do something I realy couldn't( which I realize now) what I wanted was what @BrenBarn explained, I was thinking reversed() actually reversed an iterator.What It actually does is creates a reverse iterator object which will reverse iter, which makes more sense than what I thought reversed() does